# Launch .sh script by from .bat via ADB

Tags: android, shell, sh, adb, root

My config is Google Pixel 128gb, android 10, Magisk 20.4 + 8.0.0 manager, have the mysterious problem!

I need to use .bat script, who have some code `adb shell "sh sdcard/airplane.sh"`
But it's not working!
Got error `cmd: Failure calling service activity: Failed transaction (2147483646)`
If I type it in cmd by my hands in 2 lines like: `adb shell` and then `sh sdcard/airplane.sh` it works perfect!

How I can fix this? Someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting in your .bat that way:

```
adb shell
sh sdcard/airplane.sh
```

Comment: yeap, I tried, it stucks on 2 line, shell is opened and nothing happens

Comment: I guess the problem is in cmd, I use Windows 10, command line in Win is not like Linux or android. And It did not transfer second line to shell

Answer (score 0):

It was hard to explain but, after Update Magisk 21.0 + Manager 8.0.1 it work's!